# How do I properly initialize some pointers for use in healpix subroutines?

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm having trouble locating the source of an error in my code, that when run, produces a segfault. I know the error is in code that is essentially:

```
#include "chealpix.h"
double *theta, *phi;
pix2ang_nest(8, 2, theta, phi);
```

The output of valgrind is:

```
Use of uninitialised value of size 8
Call stack:
pix2ang_z_phi
pix2ang_nest
main
```

I'm fairly confident the sources of this error are (as valgrind says) the uninitialized pointers `theta` and `phi`. My problem is: how do I initialize these properly? My understanding was that I am to pass these pointers to the function `pix2ang_nest()`, and it is the job of this function to put the return values in the memory where `theta` and `phi` point to. To use these variables, I would then dereference them with `*` e.g. `cos(*theta);`. In this case, I expected the initialization to take place within `pix2ang_nest()`. Would anyone mind, please, clarifying this for me?

Additionally,

The only line specified in the valgrind message is the line where `pix2ang_nest(8, 2, theta, phi);` is called. In other words, I'm not getting the lines of healpix code where I'm causing the error. I don't know if this is an artifact of healpix being in fortran or if I have not compiled it correctly. Other functions from healpix, however, do run and have the correct output. This is a separate concern, but I'd be interested in anyone's thoughts on it as well.

Comment: And the reason for spamming tags for two different languages? Remove the unrelated tag.

Comment: _Spamming_ is a little harsh. I included the c++ tag since I am using code like the above in a larger c++ project. If, for any reason, the c++ code became relevant, the tag would be too. Since it turned out to be simple, I removed it like you asked.

Comment: If you compile as C++, it is not C! They are different languages. Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics!.

Comment: Gosh dern it tiger, you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latter two values are "out" parameters, so you could call it by taking the address of stack-allocated variables.

```
#include "chealpix.h"
double theta, phi;
pix2ang_nest(8, 2, &theta, &phi);
```

After this `theta` and `phi` should contain values that were populated within the function.

Comment: _Thank you._ I feel really silly since my whole understanding was bass-ackwards.

Answer (score 0):

The function is most likely expecting these pointers to point to allocated memory.  Since you haven't allocated memory for these pointers, the function will invoke undefined behavior when it dereferences them.

Rather than creating pointers, create variables of the base type and pass in their addresses.

```
double theta, phi;
pix2ang_nest(8, 2, &theta, &phi);
```